# identify user in apple login with different app_id oauth client

Tags: ios, oauth, apple-login

I am using Apple OAuth login in my two apps. I identify users using the "sub" claim that can be obtained from the id_token each time they log in. Since it has to identify as the same user in both apps if it's the same account, I need to receive the same sub token.

I've created OAuth clients with different APP_IDs for each of the two apps, but I confirmed that I can receive the same sub value for the same account.

Is it okay to follow this policy for the login feature? I am curious if there is any official documentation that I can refer to on this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple) can be helpful for your question but, it's always a good idea to add extra layers of security **to directly your app** or **from** **API Gateway**.